# Make paragraph and table inline and placing in the middle of container

Tags: html, css

Here below is my code:

```css
#myTable {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>
    Title
  </p>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="input1" id="input1" type="radio" value="1">
        <label for="input1">No</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="input2" id="input2" type="radio" value="2">
        <label for="input2">Yes</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is `p` and `table` don't fit in a line vertically. How could I fix this?

Comment: Add some [margin](https://jsfiddle.net/v1pk2Lmc/)

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` doesn't work for *floated* elements - try flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/ezLs4ftg/

Comment: @kukkuz: Great Nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the margin-top of p tag

```
p {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/gjwms4n1/4/

Updated:

You can remove float left and use display: inline-block

```
#myTable {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;

  font-size: 24px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/smytrqe7/3/

Comment: Thank but `5px` is constant and If I change some thing it doesn't look like good: [https://jsfiddle.net/p2o4jf6z/]

Answer (score 1):

If you can get rid of floats (which might be really beneficial), treat both elements as **inline-blocks/inline-tables** like this:

```
#myTable {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image: Screenshot from sandbox]

```css
#myTable {
      display: inline-table;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    p {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>
    Title
  </p>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="input1" id="input1" type="radio" value="1">
        <label for="input1">No</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="input2" id="input2" type="radio" value="2">
        <label for="input2">Yes</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: besides: this solution works fully on IE8+ where flex-box have only partial support on IE

Answer (score 0):

**Update in CSS:**

```
p {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:0px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7metuxy/)

**Just check with this also:**

```
#container {
  display: table
}
#myTable {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cx3rnpmv/)

Comment: first option assumes single line solution, which in some cases might be bummer, and since this is StackOverflow if you would remove paragraph from second method (since it's unnecessary) I would love to leave you upvote

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: what happened to second option? :)
I was thinking only about removing empty paragraph ```<p></p>``` form HTML snippet

Comment: @pkolawa I think that's not a better option for the editing in HTML, anybody can do that simply. That's why :)

Comment: Ageed but we are on StackOverflow, so some people might just copy the code and unconciously place empty paragraph and after blame you for beeing laughed for leaving trash in their code ;)

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for that, I just forget to remove the empty p tag :)